# GraphQLDocumentError: Unknown type "Int"

Tags: graphql, typegraphql

I am trying to follow Ben Awad's lireddit tutorial.

At 6.49, he demonstrates how to assign a type to an argument where it's needed to override a default expected value.

The resolver has:

```
@Resolver()
  export class PostResolver {
    @Query(() => [Post])
    async posts(
      @Arg("limit", () => Int) limit: number,
      @Arg("cursor", () => String, { nullable: true }) cursor: string | null
    ): Promise<Post[]> {
      const realLimit = Math.min(50, limit);
      
      const qb = getConnection()
        .getRepository(Post)
        .createQueryBuilder("p")
        .orderBy('"createdAt"', "DESC")
        .take(realLimit)
        
        if (cursor) {
          qb.where('"createdAt" < :cursor',  new Date ( parseInt(cursor)) )
        }
       return qb.getMany();
    }
```

When I try to generate types with this it fails. I get errors that say:

1. GraphQLDocumentError: Unknown type "Int". [Note: Int is imported from type-graphql]
2. Unknown argument "cursor" on field "Query.posts".
3. Unknown argument "limit" on field "Query.posts".

Can anyone help with how to get the resolver in a format that will allow graphql to generate the types? I've seen some posts on here that describe using Floats instead of Ints for numbers, but I think that's going against the grain of what the docs say I should be able to achieve.

Ben shows how he inspects the graphql docs to find what the query expects for argument types. I can't get the same feedback from my docs.

[image]

In [this example](https://github.com/MichalLytek/type-graphql/blob/master/examples/resolvers-inheritance/person/person.resolver.ts), the Arg for limit is defined slightly differently, as follows:

@Arg("limit", type => Int) limit: number,

The word 'type' doesn't appear to be defined anywhere and this use case generates an error that says 'type is declared but not used'.

I'm stuck now because I deleted my node_modules and dist folders in the web side, and tried to re-run yarn. The node_modules got reinstalled, but the dist folder did not get recreated (I think that might happen if I can succeed in running: "graphql-codegen --config codegen.yml" (that's a guess).

So now I can't start the server to try to run that generator again.

Comment: https://github.com/armandsalle/ben-awad-lireddit-server/blob/main/src/resolvers/post.ts

Comment: Hi @xadm - is there something that you've found useful in this link to another version of the posts resolver? I tried commenting mine and using this one, but I still get the same errors when I try to run yarn gen.

Comment: just run/follow some working example/tutorials

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @xadm. I'm trying to understand how this tutorial works so that I can learn how to interact with graphql. That's why a tutorial is helpful. I havne't found anything instructive in the resolver you shared. Thank you for suggesting that I review it. While it does expand on the tutorial file, it does not answer or offer any insight that may help solve the problem I've posted.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why this was necessary or how it worked, but I deleted the client side node_modules folder and the dist folder. I reran yarn to reinstall node_modules (not sure how dist was recreated). I shut everything down, restarted the vs code workspace and was able to generate the types.

This makes no sense to me at all. If anyone has any skills in how to search for reasons why this sort of thing happens, I'd love to understand what's going on.

Comment: Did this work? If not, then this is supposed to e a comment and not an answer.

Comment: Try this instead: `@Arg("limit", () => Int)`

Comment: @cdaiga it did work. i have no idea how or why